# How to use a font from a file in SharpDX?

Tags: c#, windows-8, direct2d, sharpdx

i want to generate image for windows 8 app, i'm going to use SharpDX API

here is the code sample which i thankfully coped and paste

```
private MemoryStream RenderStaticTextToBitmap()
    {
        var width = 400;
        var height = 100;
        var pixelFormat = WicPixelFormat.Format32bppBGR;

        var wicFactory = new ImagingFactory();
        var dddFactory = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory();
        var dwFactory = new SharpDX.DirectWrite.Factory();

        var wicBitmap = new Bitmap(
            wicFactory,
            width,
            height,
            pixelFormat,
            BitmapCreateCacheOption.CacheOnLoad);

        var renderTargetProperties = new RenderTargetProperties(
            RenderTargetType.Default,
            new D2DPixelFormat(Format.Unknown, AlphaMode.Unknown),
            0,
            0,
            RenderTargetUsage.None,
            FeatureLevel.Level_DEFAULT);
        var renderTarget = new WicRenderTarget(
            dddFactory,
            wicBitmap,
            renderTargetProperties)
        {
            TextAntialiasMode = TextAntialiasMode.Cleartype
        };

        renderTarget.BeginDraw();

        var textFormat = new TextFormat(dwFactory, "Consolas", 48)
        {
            TextAlignment = SharpDX.DirectWrite.TextAlignment.Center,
            ParagraphAlignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center
        };
        var textBrush = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.SolidColorBrush(
            renderTarget,
            SharpDX.Colors.Blue);

        renderTarget.Clear(Colors.White);
        renderTarget.DrawText(
            "Hi, mom!",
            textFormat,
            new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height),
            textBrush);

        renderTarget.EndDraw();

        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        var stream = new WICStream(
            wicFactory,
            ms);

        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder(wicFactory);
        encoder.Initialize(stream);

        var frameEncoder = new BitmapFrameEncode(encoder);
        frameEncoder.Initialize();
        frameEncoder.SetSize(width, height);
        frameEncoder.PixelFormat = WicPixelFormat.FormatDontCare;
        frameEncoder.WriteSource(wicBitmap);
        frameEncoder.Commit();

        encoder.Commit();

        frameEncoder.Dispose();
        encoder.Dispose();
        stream.Dispose();

        ms.Position = 0;
        return ms;
    }
```

this working in excellent way with installed fonts .... i have font in the assets folder and i want to use -i have about 604 custom fonts and i chose the font dynamically- , i know there is away to load file from folder .... help plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, afaik, there is no API in DirectWrite that supports this easily. You need to develop your own font loader and related classes. There is the SharpDX sample [CustomFont](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/WindowsDesktop/DirectWrite/CustomFont) that is loading fonts from resources, so you could adapt it to load from another location.