# Enumerate supported characters/glyphs in a specific font with UWP/C#

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

Trying to figure out if there is a way in a Windows 10 (UWP) store app to enumerate or list the supported characters in a specific font (side note: the fonts I need to 'inspect' are stored locally in the app package).

There are [similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439551/get-supported-characters-of-a-font-in-c-sharp) for Win32 apps, but nothing that I've seen that works for UWP apps.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## New Answer - Checking custom font files

You can check if a font maps a glyph to particular Unicode character/code via DirectWrite using the [IDWriteFontFace::GetGlyphIndices method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370998(v=vs.85).aspx). There is a C# wrapper for DirectWrite as part of the SharpDx library, specifically the [SharpDX.Direct2D1 package on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX.Direct2D1/).

I have made an example from the [SharpDx Directwrite example on github](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Desktop/DirectWrite/CustomFont). I used a file selector dialog to open the files since UWP apps are not allowed to access most of the file system unless the user selects the files themselves. You can also put the fonts with your app. I downloaded two free fonts to test, "Aileron" and "Grundschrift". I just whipped it up really fast to show you its not that hard, but the code doesn't follow best practices I am sure. First, add the following three classes from the SharpDx Directwrite custom font example: `ResourceFontFileStream.cs`, `ResourceFontLoader.cs`, and `ResourceFontFileEnumerator.cs`. Change the namespaces to your project namespace. In `ResourceFontLoader.cs` change the constructor to this:

```
public ResourceFontLoader(Factory factory, List<Stream> fontfiles)
{
    _factory = factory;
    var AnyFontsLoaded = false;
    foreach (var filename in fontfiles)
    {
        try
        {
            using (filename)
            {
                var fontBytes = Utilities.ReadStream(filename);
                var stream = new DataStream(fontBytes.Length, true, true);
                stream.Write(fontBytes, 0, fontBytes.Length);
                stream.Position = 0;
                _fontStreams.Add(new ResourceFontFileStream(stream));
                AnyFontsLoaded = true;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            // Handle all file exceptions how you see fit
            throw;
        }
    }
    if (AnyFontsLoaded)
    {
        // Build a Key storage that stores the index of the font
        _keyStream = new DataStream(sizeof(int) * _fontStreams.Count, true, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < _fontStreams.Count; i++)
            _keyStream.Write((int)i);
        _keyStream.Position = 0;

        // Register the 
        _factory.RegisterFontFileLoader(this);
        _factory.RegisterFontCollectionLoader(this);
    }
}
```

In your testing main page:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ResourceFontLoader CurrentResourceFontLoader { get; set; }
    public FontCollection CurrentFontCollection { get; set; }
    public SharpDX.DirectWrite.Factory FactoryDWrite { get; private set; }
    public List<Stream> customFontStreams { get; set; }
    public List<string> FontFamilyNames { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        customFontStreams = new List<Stream>();
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    async Task LoadCustomFonts()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Font Families
            FontFamilyNames = new List<string> { "Aileron", "Grundschrift" };
            // Character codes to check for:
            int[] codes = { 0x41, 0x6f, 0x7c, 0xc2aa, 0xD7A3 };
            FactoryDWrite = new SharpDX.DirectWrite.Factory();
            CurrentResourceFontLoader = new ResourceFontLoader(FactoryDWrite, customFontStreams);
            CurrentFontCollection = new FontCollection(FactoryDWrite, CurrentResourceFontLoader, CurrentResourceFontLoader.Key);

            foreach (var fontfamilyname in FontFamilyNames)
            {
                int familyIndex;
                CurrentFontCollection.FindFamilyName(fontfamilyname, out familyIndex);

                using (var fontFamily = CurrentFontCollection.GetFontFamily(familyIndex))
                {
                    var font = fontFamily.GetFont(0);

                    using (var fontface = new FontFace(font))
                    {
                        var results = fontface.GetGlyphIndices(codes);
                        for (int i = 0; i < codes.Length - 1; i++)
                        {
                            if (results[i] > 0)
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine("Contains the unicode character " + codes[i]);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine("Does not contain the unicode character " + codes[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".otf");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".ttf");
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
        if (files.Count > 0)
        {


            // Application now has read/write access to the picked file(s) 
            foreach (StorageFile file in files)
            {
                customFontStreams.Add(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync());
            }
            await LoadCustomFonts();
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Original Answer - Checking system fonts:

An example using the SharpDX.Direct2D1 package to check if a font has certain characters:

```
var fontName = "Segoe UI";

using (var factory = new Factory(FactoryType.Shared))
{
    using (var fontCollection = factory.GetSystemFontCollection(true))
    {
        int familyIndex;
        fontCollection.FindFamilyName(fontName, out familyIndex);

        using (var fontFamily = fontCollection.GetFontFamily(familyIndex))
        {
            var font = fontFamily.GetFont(0);

            using (var fontface = new FontFace(font))
            {
                int[] codes = { 0x41, 0x6f, 0x7c, 0xc2aa, 0xD7A3 };

                var results = fontface.GetGlyphIndices(codes);
                for (int i = 0; i < codes.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (results[i] > 0)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Contains the unicode character " + codes[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Does not contain the unicode character " + codes[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising - my only issue is that the font files I'm working with are not system fonts, but stored locally. Any idea if this works for a font file such as: /Fonts/AnonymousPro-regular.ttf#Anonymous Pro ?

Comment: The SharpDx github has an example of using custom fonts, its a little long to replicate here. [Take a look](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Desktop/DirectWrite/CustomFont)

Comment: After scouring the code, I still haven't had any luck getting a custom font to work with SharpDx. I know beggars can't be choosers, but hoping for a more straightforward solution...

Comment: What kind of issues are you having? Maybe its something to do with the fonts themselves, would you be able to upload some?

Comment: According to xoofx, there is "no easy way to load from a different location" via SharpDx. That is where I'm stuck is finding how to re-direct the fontCollection to look for my fonts in the /Fonts file located in my app package. This was enlightening (although discouraging) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855964/how-to-use-a-font-from-a-file-in-sharpdx

Comment: @erickfiveten I edited my post to show how to do that, please check it.

Comment: Thanks Evan - I got it working! Performance is a little bit of an issue, but expected when scanning a font for each of 10,000 glyphs. For anyone who just needs the number of glyphs, there is fontface.GlyphCount with much speedier performance.